# Solving $y'+p(x)y^2 = q(x)$ type of equation via variation of parameters.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is an extended version of my previous post [How to solve $y' = \frac{1}{4} \cos^2(x) + y^2(x) \sin^2(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122944/how-to-solve-y-frac14-cos2x-y2x-sin2x)

Following [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters), I know how to handle the general solutions for $y'(x) + p(x)y = q(x)$ but how about $y'(x) + p(x)y^2(x) = q(x)$?

Based on the hint by @Claude Leibovici, I came up with following things:

Following the steps in Wiki,

\begin{align}
y_0'+p(x)y_0^2 =0 \quad \Rightarrow  - \frac{1}{y_0} = - \int p(x) dx \quad \Rightarrow \quad y_0(x) = \frac{1}{\int p(x) dx + C }
\end{align}

Now replacing constant $C$ to $C(x)$

\begin{align}
&y_p(x) = \frac{1}{\int(p(x)dx+C(x)} \\
&y_p'(x) = -\left(p(x)+C'(x)\right)y_p^2(x) \\
& C'(x) = \frac{q(x)}{y_p^2(x)} \quad \Rightarrow \quad C(x) = \int \frac{q(x)}{y_p^2(x)}dx
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
C(x) =  \int \frac{q(x)}{\left(\int p(x) dx + C(x) \right)^2 }
\end{align}
which is recursive.

Is variation of parameters works well for $y'(x) + p(x)y(x) =q(x)$? Or am i doing some mistake?

Comment: No, this is still a Riccati equation, not a linear equation, so setting the right side to zero is not very helpful.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, Okay then I will look on Riccati equations, Thanks!